# find global min/max among local extreme using awk or shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I can find local min. or local max. of my two column data (x, y) by using following awk codes.

```
awk 'prev!=""&&prev<=prev2&&prev<=$2{print line}{prev2=prev;prev=$2;line=$0}' file # this is for local min.

awk 'prev!=""&&prev>=prev2&&prev>=$2{print line}{prev2=prev;prev=$2;line=$0}' file # this is for local max.
```

Qs:

1. Could you explain above codes shortly? I just used and saw it works, but don't know how it works...
2. How could I find global min/max after local min/max are found by the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Local Minimum Explained

Let's consider the code for the local minimum.  It uses three variables:

- `prev2` is the value of the second column from two lines ago
- `prev` is the value of the second column from the previous line
- `line` is the previous line

The code consists of two parts:

1. `prev!="" && prev<=prev2 && prev<=$2 {print line}`

   If `prev` has been assigned a value (in other words, if we are not on the first line) and that value is less than both `prev2` and the current 2nd column, `$2`, then we know that the previous line was a local minimum and we print it.
2. `prev2=prev; prev=$2; line=$0`

   Here we update the variables so that they will be correct when we test the next line.

#### Local Maximum Explained

The code for local maximum is exactly analogous to the local minimum code except that we look for `prev` to be larger than either `prev2` or `$2`.

#### Global Minimum

To find the line with the smallest second column:

```
awk '!m || $2<m {m=$2; line=$0;} END{print line;}' file
```

#### Global Maximum

```
awk '!m || $2>m {m=$2; line=$0;} END{print line;}' file
```